# How to pass date string to datetime field in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I need the number (as integer) of users that signed up (User.date_joined) between '2016-01-01'(string) and '2016-04-01' (string) (both dates fully included)

The below queries  didn't give me accurate results, since the date_joined is  datetime field

```
User.objects.filter(date_joined__gte='2016-01-01',date_joined_lte='2016-04-01').count()
User.objects.filter(date_joined__range('2016-01-01 00:00:00','2016-04-01 12:59:59')).count()
```

I am new to django and python , want to know how to pass the string date values to datetime field and use of range function

Comment: Use a `datetime.datetime` object, not a string.

Comment: can you help me with the ORM statement please

Answer (score 1):

```
dt1 = datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 1) # midnight
dt2 = dt1 + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
User.objects.filter(date_joined__range=(dt1, dt2)).count()
```